# Any 'odd unit fraction' whose denominator is not $1$ can be represented as the sum of three different 'odd unit fractions'?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions, egyptian-fractions

Let us call a fraction whose denominator is odd '**odd fraction**'. Also, let us call an odd fraction whose numerator is 1  '**odd unit fraction**'.

Then, here is my question.

> **Question** : Is the following true?
>
> "Any odd unit fraction whose denominator is not $1$ can be represented as the sum of three different odd unit fractions."

**Motivation** : I've been asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512263/any-odd-fraction-can-be-represented-as-the-finite-sum-of-different-odd-unit-f). Then, I reached the above expectation.

**Examples** :

$$\frac 13=\frac 15+\frac 19+\frac 1{45}$$
$$\frac 15=\frac 1{7}+\frac 1{21}+\frac 1{105}$$
$$\frac 17=\frac 19+\frac 1{33}+\frac 1{693}$$
$$\frac 19=\frac 1{11}+\frac 1{51}+\frac 1{1683}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\frac 1{99}=\frac 1{101}+\frac 1{5001}+\frac 1{16668333}$$
$$\vdots$$

Comment: I have posted an answer which should be correct, albeit late @mathlove.  Please do check it out below!  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is essentially answered in this closely related question:

[On A Splitting Equation of an Egyptian fraction to Egyptian fractions such that all produced fractions have odd denominators.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3585135)

I quote verbatim from the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3585692/28816) by [MSE user Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/82961):

> A general solution is for every positive integer $\ n\ $ :

- If $n$ is odd , then $$\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{6n+3}+\frac{1}{18n^2+21n+6}=\frac{1}{2n+1}$$ is a solution with odd denominators
- If $n$ is even , then $$\frac{1}{3n+3}+\frac{1}{6n+3}+\frac{1}{6n^2+9n+3}=\frac{1}{2n+1}$$ is a solution with odd denominators

> So, for every odd $\ k\ge 3\ $ we can write $\ \frac 1k\ $ with $\ 3\ $ distinct fractions with odd denominators.

Note that Peter's solution has

> $$18n^2 + 21n + 6 = 3(2n + 1)(3n + 2)$$
>   $$6n^2 + 9n + 3 = 3(2n + 1)(n + 1).$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is not a multiple of 3, then $$\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{3}{(n+2)(n+4)}+\frac{1}{n(n+2)(n+4)}$$
Second try: You have the first fraction is $1/(n+2)$.  Then you want to solve $$\frac{2}{n(n+2)}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$$
Rearrange that into $(2a-n(n+2))(2b-n(n+2))=n^2(n+2)^2$  You can make the right-hand side equal to $pq$, where both $p$ and $q$ are $3\bmod 4$.  (Take $p=n$ or $p=n+2$) Then $a$ and $b$ will be odd.
So $a=n(n+3)/2, b=n(n+2)(n+3)/2$ or $a=(n+1)(n+2)/2, b=n(n+2)(n+1)/2$

Comment: Sadly, I don't think it's true though.

Comment: This is not correct; take any $n$ other than $7$, e.g. $n=5$ or $n=11$. In fact, $\frac1n - \frac1{n+2} - \frac3{(n+2)(n+4)} = \frac{8-n}{n(n+2)(n+4)}$