# On A Splitting Equation of an Egyptian fraction to Egyptian fractions such that all produced fractions have odd denominators - Part II

Tags: elementary-number-theory, egyptian-fractions

This post is inspired by this earlier question:

[On A Splitting Equation of an Egyptian fraction to Egyptian fractions such that all produced fractions have odd denominators.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3585135)

I quote:

> An example of a splitting to *Odd Egyptian fraction* is given below:
>   $$\frac{1}{3}= \frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{45}$$
>   $$\frac{1}{5}= \frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{45}$$
>   $$\frac{1}{7}= \frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{21}+\frac{1}{35}$$
>   $$\frac{1}{7}= \frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{45}+\frac{1}{105}$$
>   $$\frac{1}{9}= \frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{35}+\frac{1}{63}$$
>   $$\frac{1}{11}= \frac{1}{21}+\frac{1}{33}+\frac{1}{77}$$
>   **Notice that**
>   $$3 \mid 45$$
>   $$5 \mid 45$$
>   $$7 \mid 35$$
>   $$7 \mid 105$$
>   $$9 \mid 63$$
>   $$11 \mid 77$$

**My question is:**

> If
>   $$\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\frac{1}{x_3}$$
>   where all of $y$, $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are **distinct** positive integers, and $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$, does it follow that $y \mid x_3$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

In the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3585692/28816), we have the following:

> A general solution is for every positive integer $\ n\ $ :

- If $n$ is odd , then $$\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{6n+3}+\frac{1}{18n^2+21n+6}=\frac{1}{2n+1}$$ is a solution with odd denominators
- If $n$ is even , then $$\frac{1}{3n+3}+\frac{1}{6n+3}+\frac{1}{6n^2+9n+3}=\frac{1}{2n+1}$$ is a solution with odd denominators

> So, for every odd $\ k\ge 3\ $ we can write $\ \frac 1k\ $ with $\ 3\ $ distinct fractions with odd denominators.

**Notice that**

> $$18n^2 + 21n + 6 = 3(2n + 1)(3n + 2)$$
>   $$6n^2 + 9n + 3 = 3(2n + 1)(n + 1).$$

**Follow-Up Questions**

> If the answer to my first question is *YES*, how can such a claim be proved?  Lastly, if the answer to my first question is *NO*, what is/are some of the smallest counterexample(s)?

The link below is useful for further details about Egyptian fractions: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fractions/egyptian.html#section9.5

Comment: Thank you for providing the two counterexamples in your last comment, @quasi!  If you write that out as an actual answer, then I will accept it.  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of counterexamples . . .

A counterexample with $y=2$:
$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{15}$$
A counterexample with all odd denominators:
$$\frac{1}{9}=\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{63}+\frac{1}{231}$$
A counterexample such that none of $y,x_1,x_2,x_3$ is a multiple of one of the others:
$$\frac{1}{10}=\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{55}+\frac{1}{66}$$